# R glm summary lists every value of independent variable

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm running a glm in r on a dataframe with 2 values.

```
str(INV)
'data.frame':   5614 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ MSACode: Factor w/ 70 levels "40","80","440",..: 37 64 58 56 66 14 38 37 66 14 ...
 $ NotPaid: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The code I used to run it:

```
GlmModel <- glm(NotPaid ~ MSACode,family=binomial(link="logit"),data=training)
print(summary(GlmModel))
```

The result from the summary is showing the individual values rather than just one value for the field.

```
> print(summary(GlmModel))

Call:
glm(formula = NotPaid ~ MSACode, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = training)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.9728  -0.8352  -0.6501   0.9346   2.8245  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -1.657e+01  1.697e+03  -0.010    0.992
MSACode80    1.462e+01  1.697e+03   0.009    0.993
MSACode440  -7.494e-07  1.924e+03   0.000    1.000
MSACode520   1.547e+01  1.697e+03   0.009    0.993
MSACode640   1.587e+01  1.697e+03   0.009    0.993
MSACode720   1.477e+01  1.697e+03   0.009    0.993
MSACode870   1.657e+01  1.697e+03   0.010    0.992
MSACode1080  1.455e+01  1.697e+03   0.009    0.993
```

I don't understand these results - why is it showing each MSACode value separately? Thanks.

Comment: It seems that MSACod is interpreted as a categorical variable, is it what you wanted?

Comment: `MSACode` likely is a factor and not integer or numeric. Check types with `str(training)`.

Comment: @YacineHajji Yes, it is a categorical variable.

Comment: @Parfait Yes, it is a factor.

Comment: this has to be a duplicate, right?  `INV <- transform(INV, MSACode = as.numeric(as.character(MSACode)))`

Comment: @BenBolker - This is it. If you add it as an answer, I'll mark it answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but can't find it.

The problem is that, because `MSACode` is a factor (possibly because of a value in that column of an input file that couldn't be interpreted as numeric), R is assuming you want to treat it as a categorical rather than as a continuous predictor — hence, it gives you `n-1` parameters (where `n` is the number of levels) rather than 1 to describe its effect.  You can convert it back to numeric by:

```r
INV <- transform(INV, 
    MSACode = as.numeric(as.character(MSACode)))
```

and then re-run your model. ([This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information) explains why we need `as.numeric(as.character(.))` rather than `as.numeric()`, and explains that `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` is more efficient — although I rarely bother worrying about that level of efficiency ...)

Comment: I looked for it too and was surprised to not find it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also, OP and future readers, `as.character` here is important. See why in this [popular R post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/1422451).